# Am I allowed to use famous peoples' faces in an app?

Tags: copyright, photography, right-of-publicity

For example, can I use David Cameron's face in an app, without permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run into these problems:

**Copyright in the picture**: you would need to own the copyright (e.g. by taking the photo yourself), have permission of the copyright holder or use a photo in the public domain.

**Trademark in the face**: a sufficiently famous person can have trademark in their appearance. If so, you cannot use it in such a way that a person could believe that that person endorses your app.

**Model release** some jurisdictions require a model release before a photograph of a person can be used for a commercial purpose. Search photo on this site for several questions on this.