# Is using a person's face in satirical video without video legal?

Tags: privacy, photography, right-of-publicity

I Have Been Taking Photos Of People And Putting Them On Youtube Videos In Satirical Context Without Consent. In One Case, It Was Against Their Will. I Do Not Leak Any Information Or Send Hate Or Anything Towards Them. All I Do Is Post Pictures Calling Them Things. Is This Legal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I allowed to use peoples faces in an app?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6548/am-i-allowed-to-use-peoples-faces-in-an-app)

Comment: Why Are You Not Using Proper Capitalization

Comment: @DaleM Idk Just A Habit

Comment: Every Thing Is In Title Case Why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, there are some contexts where permission is required. First, if you are commercially exploiting a person's image, then permission is required: this is about civil [personality rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_rights) (which in California are also recognized statutorily). That doesn't seem applicable here. The other is ["video voyerism"](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1801), which is a federal crime, and that is about posting pictures of someone's privates, which I also assume is not applicable here.